# Oracle SQL Stored Procedure Cursor print

Tags: sql, database, oracle

Ok so I am working on a homework assignment using stored procedures.

Essentially i am just trying to use a stored procedure to run a query then print the results.

Here is what i have so far.

```
create or replace procedure movie_actors (mtitle varchars)as
DECLARE
CURSOR c1 is SELECT "NAME",GENDER,ADDRESS FROM MOVIESTAR WHERE "NAME" in(
SELECT STARNAME FROM STARSIN WHERE MOVIETITLE=mtitle);
actor_name MOVIESTAR.NAME%TYPE;
actor_gender MOVIESTAR.NAME%TYPE;
actor_address MOVIESTAR.ADDRESS%TYPE;
BEGIN
LOOP
   FETCH c1 INTO actor_name;
   FETCH c1 INTO actor_gender;
   FETCH c1 INTO actor_address;
   EXIT WHEN c1%NOTFOUND;
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(mtitle ||', '||actor_name||': '||actor_gender||', '||actor_address); 
END LOOP;
END;
```

I am new to databases and stored procedures. I am not sure if i am really going about this the best way.

It should be pretty simple, I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

This is the compiler error i am getting.

```
Error(2,1): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "DECLARE" when expecting one of the   
following:     begin function pragma procedure subtype type <an identifier>    <a   
double-quoted delimited-identifier> current cursor delete    exists prior external 
language The symbol "begin" was substituted for "DECLARE" to continue. 

Error(16,4): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the
following:     ( begin case declare end exception exit for goto if loop mod    
null pragma raise return select update while with    <an identifier> <a double-quoted 
delimited-identifier>    <a bind variable> << continue close current delete fetch lock 
insert open rollback savepoint set sql execute commit forall    merge pipe purge
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you have an invalid type:

```
create or replace procedure movie_actors (mtitle varchars)as
                                                        ^
```

This should be `varchar2`, not `varchars`.

Second, you don't need the `DECLARE` here. The "as" kinda substitutes for it. Start your proc like this:

```
create or replace procedure movie_actors (mtitle varchar2)as
  CURSOR c1
```

Finally, I strongly recommend changing this:

```
CURSOR c1 is SELECT "NAME",GENDER,ADDRESS FROM MOVIESTAR WHERE "NAME"
```

... to this (no double quotes):

```
CURSOR c1 is SELECT NAME,GENDER,ADDRESS FROM MOVIESTAR WHERE NAME
```

The double quotes will make the column name case sensitive. You're lucky in this case because the default in Oracle is uppercase, but sooner or later using double quotes like this will cause you trouble - there are plenty of StackOverflow postings from frustrated users who've lost hours or time from using double quotes when they didn't have to.

Comment: Awesome that is good advice. I thought I had to escape NAME because it is a keyword, but it seems to work just fine. Thank you for your help.